# Responding with basic card on AoG from php webhook through api.ai

Tags: php, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to create a card with my webhook service. my website is in php but I don't know how to respond to api.ai in a way to display my result in card format on client's phone. I ask my question with more detail in [here](https://discuss.api.ai/t/webhook-php-and-creating-card/9510).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Considering, you know receiving and checking action from Api.ai request in php

For responding with the card, you can use this:

```
$request== file_get_contents("php://input");
$messages=[];
// Building Card
 array_push($messages, array(
    "type"=> "basic_card",
    "platform"=> "google",
    "title"=> "Card title",
    "subtitle"=> "card subtitle",
    "image"=>[
      "url"=>'http://image-url',
      "accessibility_text"=>'image-alt'
      ],
      "formattedText"=> 'Text for card',
      "buttons"=> [
        [
          "title"=> "Button title",
          "openUrlAction"=> [
            "url"=> "http://url redirect for button"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      )
   );
  // Adding simple response (mandatory)
  array_push($messages, array(
     "type"=> "simple_response",
     "platform"=> "google",
     "textToSpeech"=> "Here is speech and additional msg for card"
    )
  );
  $response=array(
          "source" => $request["result"]["source"],
          "speech" => "Speech for response",
          "messages" => $messages,
          "contextOut" => array()
      );
 json_encode($response);
```

**Make sure you don't push more than one card and have 'simple response' with it.**

Comment: it's not in the doc where should I find it?

Comment: yes and I'm thankful but I might want to add more options or more than one card there is no doc about it?. by the way your code didn't work I change it a little bit.

Comment: Ya, I didn't write all part, action you had to handle.
And if you want more than 1 card, you should try carousel or list.

Comment: I have one question what is the `option` in list that is require. and when I click on the item in the list it just says the title what if I want to say my sentence to trigger an Intent so I can show the details. I'm confuse between using Intents or Entities. can u give a hint? thanks

Comment: `option key` in list and carousel is to invoke other intent.
Like you have one intent `int1` which is invoked when a user says: 'I am a boy', and if you use 'I am a boy' as `option key` for a list item, `int1` will be invoked by clicking on that item.

Comment: Entities are like possible values for a parameter. Like in above example `boy` can be an entity of class `@Genders`, which can have more possibilities. You use intents and `user says` blank in intent can use Entities if you want.